# Increasing the opacity of a color across several divs using SASS

Tags: html, math, sass

I have 18 divs and I have made it so for each div going first to last I am mixing 2 colors going from $color-1 and ending up with $color-2. And it works perfectly as it should. I then wanted to add opacity which works too except I am a bit confused with some of the math (not my strong point).

Geting the opacity to be in incremental steps from *1 - 18* is easy as shown here `$opacity: ((1 / $itemCount) * $i);` however I am not wanting it to be from *0 - 1* I would like the opacity to range in 18 steps from *0.2 - 0.8* and that is where I have my confusion, I can't get my head around the math to calculate that.

```
@for $i from 1 through 18 {
  $itemCount: 18;
  $weight: (( 100% / $itemCount ) * $i );
  $opacity: ((1 / $itemCount) * $i);
  $mix: mix($color-1, $color-2, $weight);
  %item-color-#{$i}{
    background: rgba( $mix, $opacity);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit complicated situation, I manage to do it like that

```
    $list: ();
    $i: 0.2;
    $itemCount: 18;
    @while $i < 0.8 {
      $list: (append($list, $i));
      $i: $i + 0.6/$itemCount;
    }

    $z: 1;
    @while $z < 19 {
      p-#{$z} {
        padding: nth($list, $z);
      }
      $z: $z + 1;
    }
```

You have to create an empty list and append in that list every value between 0.2 and 0.8. The steps are 18 so the pace will be (0.8 - 0.2)/18

then you have to create another while statement where you should pick the value from that list which now has all the needed values.

The above is an example so you can see the output.

An example: http://sassmeister.com/gist/5dde2f3468b6b2265002

Comment: I found an easier way based upon what you suggested see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:

```
@for $i from 1 through 18 {
  $itemCount: 18;
  $weight: (( 100% / $itemCount ) * $i );
  $min-opacity: 0.3;
  $max-opacity: 0.9;
  $opacity-range: $max-opacity - $min-opacity;
  $opacity: ((($opacity-range/$itemCount)*$i)+$min-opacity);
  $mix: mix($color-1, $color-2, $weight);
  %item-color-#{$i}{
    background: rgba( $mix, $opacity);
  }
}
```